# Constraint the interface of ios application to look same in all simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I make my application in xcode 8. I set my interface design in iphone 5 simulator in main.storyboard. My interface has scroll view and the image button all is put inside the scroll view. I constraint the scroll view and image buttons with reset to suggested constraint. When run in simulator, only iphone 5 look nice but other iphone look no good. I post my output in below, i think it is easy to understand what i want? If know how to do, please tell me. I want my application design look same in all simulator. First picture is iphone 5 and second picture is iphone 7 plus.

Output:

[image]

[image]